# Iterator through std::set using find() won't work. What's going wrong?

Tags: c++, iterator, set

I am trying to create a program that has a list of contacts where the user can search for a contact's name based on a phone number.  Sorry for including so much code but it is necessary for understanding my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

struct ContactItem
{
    string name;
    string phoneNumber;
    string displayAs;

    ContactItem(const string inName, const string inNumber) : name(inName), phoneNumber(inNumber)
    {
        displayAs = name + ": " + phoneNumber;
    }

    bool operator== (const ContactItem& searchParameter) const
    {
        return (this->phoneNumber == searchParameter.phoneNumber);
    }

    bool operator< (const ContactItem& compareResult) const
    {
        return (this->name < compareResult.name);
    }

    operator const char*() const
    {
        return displayAs.c_str();
    }
};

int main()
{
    //Initialize a set and populate it with contacts of type ContactItem
    set<ContactItem> contactBook;
    contactBook.insert(ContactItem("Sally", "123654864"));
    contactBook.insert(ContactItem("Joe", "8435102654"));
    contactBook.insert(ContactItem("Steve", "8135691234"));
    contactBook.insert(ContactItem("Alice", "8432489425"));

    //Search for a contact's name by only being given their number
    cout << "Please give the number of one contact whose name you would like to know: " << endl;
    string userNumber;
    getline(cin, userNumber);

    auto findNumber = contactBook.find(ContactItem("", userNumber));

    if (findNumber != contactBook.end())
        cout << "The name of the contact whose number matches the phone number given is: " << (*findNumber).name << endl;
    else
        cout << "Contact not found" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My problem always seems to be with the line `auto findNumber = contactBook.find(userNumber);`.  Every single time I run this code, the message "Contact not found" is displayed.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Is it my redefinition of `operator==`?

The above code was inspired by Rao, Siddhartha. *Sams Teach Yourself C++ in One Hour a Day*. 8th ed., Indianapolis, IN, Sams, 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use `std::set::find` to do this.  `std::set::find` is to find an exact match, but you're looking for a partial match.  `std::set::find` is going to look at only a subset of the contacts because it knows they are sorted.  But you need to check all of the contacts, because any one of them could match the phone number.

What you need is `std::find_if` from `<algorithm>`.  `std::find_if` takes a predicate, which is a function or function-like object that can tell if you if this is the right one.

First, include `<algorithm>`

```
#include <algorithm>
```

We can use a lambda for the predicate:

```
auto findNumber =
  std::find_if(contactBook.begin(), contactBook.end(),
               [&userNumber](const ContactItem &contact) {
                 return contact.phoneNumber == userNumber;
               });
```

If you haven't worked with lambdas before, this can look pretty weird.  A lambda is like a nameless function with state.

The square brackets `[]` tell the compiler that this is a lambda.  The `&userNumber` says that, in the body of the lambda, we're going to need a reference to the `userNumber` variable that's in the current scope.  (This is called "capture by reference.")

The parentheses enclose a function-like parameter list.  `std::find_if` is going to invoke this lambda on each contact, as though it were a regular function, by passing in a reference to the contact.

The body of the lambda (in braces `{}`) is a function body that returns a `bool` to tell use whether the contact passed in meets our criteria for a match.  The body can reference the arguments passed in as well as anything "captured" from the defining scope.  In this case, we just care whether the contact's phone number matches the desired phone number.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in `std::set` [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) by default it uses `std::less` which in this case uses `ContactItem::operator<` you povided. As you compare structs by `name` field - this field is used in comparing elements, so basically you are trying to find contact with empty name. You either need to specify different comparator for this `std::set` or change `ContactItem::operator <` accordingly.

Note: unlike `std::unordered_set` `std::set` does not use `operator==` in any form, as you can also see in documentatioon:

> std::set is an associative container that contains a sorted set of
>   unique objects of type Key. Sorting is done using the key comparison
>   function Compare.

and `std::less` [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) says:

> Function object for performing comparisons. Unless specialized,
>   invokes operator< on type T.

Comment: Might be worth adding that `operator<` must implement a [strict weak ordering](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) - that's something beginners often get wrong.

Comment: This answer is all true, but it doesn't actually solve the problem.  Changing the comparator doesn't help find items that are a partial match.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy if you use comparator that igniores name and only compares phones for this `std::set` it will solve the problem.

Comment: @Slava, but it also fundamentally changes what the set contains.  With the OP's original code (which checks only the name), we're ensured that each name appears exactly once in the set, and iterating the set gives you the items in lexicographic order by name.  If you change the comparator to phone number, then each number can appear in the set only once, and iterating the set gives the contacts ordered lexicographically by the phone number string.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy according to logic this particular set exists to do lookup by phone number so I explain how to fix broken logic in this particular program. I cannot read mind and if OP would need to change field to lookup my answer would be different, but OP has to specify that.

Comment: @JesperJuhl thanks, I think your comment is a good reminder as itself

Comment: The `find` member of `std::set` (and most of the standard containers) is for finding an exact match.  This is not the right tool for finding a partial match.  For that, there's `std::find_if`.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy OP does not say he needs partical match. He needs to find `Contact` by phone number.

Comment: @Slava:  The phone number is only part of the ContactItem, so, yes, this is looking for a partial match.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `std::set` does not use your `operator ==` to find the element.  Instead it uses the same thing it uses to compare objects which is the `operator <`.  You're either going to have to change your `operator <` to compare by `phoneNumber` or provide a named contact.

You could also consider a boost [multi-index container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) that would allow you to index my name and number.

Comment: A multi-index container would be a solution, but simply changing the comparator has other, probably undesirable ramifications (for example, two contacts wouldn't be able to share a phone number).